# How to implement 50M key-value pair memcache with 4 M qps?

Tags: performance, memcached, benchmarking

The business scenario requires:

50M key-value pairs, 2K each , 100G memory in total.

About 40% of key-value will change in a second.

The Java application need Get() once and set() once for each changed pair,  it will be 50M*40%*2=4M qps (query per second) .

We tested memcached - which shows very limited qps.
Our benchmarking is very similar to results showed here
http://xmemcached.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/benchmark/benchmark.html

10,000 around qps is the limitation of one memcached server.

That mean we need 40 partitioned memcached servers in our business scenario- which seems very uneconomic and unrealistic.

In your experience, is the benchmarking accurate in term of memcached’s designed performance?

Any suggestion to tune memcached system(client or server)?

Or any other alternative memory store system that is able meet the requirement more economically?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the graphs in the benchmark you talked about you need to realize that the in many of those instances the limit was the network and not memcached. For instance, if you will have 2k values for all of your items then your maximum throughput on a GigE network if about 65k ops/sec. (1024*1024*128/2048=65536). Memcached can do a lot more operations per second than this. I have personally hit 200K ops/sec with (I think) 512b values and I have heard of others getting much higher throughput than I did. This all depends heavily on the network though.

Also, memcached is barely doing anything at 10k ops/sec. My guess is your aren't taking advantage of concurrency in your benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That's good point. I would point anyone who interests in this topic for the discussion in memcached google group here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/memcached/98ko9HhLcX4